# Built in JSON parser in .NET framework

Tags: json

For reasons I don't want to get into I find I cannot make use of the JSON.NET JSON parser from Newtonsoft. Does .NET have it's own JSON parser available in the framework?

Comment: On what platform?

Comment: It's called JavaScriptSerializer. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx